# alternate way to show function is schwarz

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

We know that $f (x)$ is in Schwarz  space if for given  $ m, k $ non negative integers  Supremum of $ |x^{m  }  f^{(k)}(x) | $ is finite over   real numbers. Is it true that $f (x)$ is Schwarz if and only if $ |x^{m  }  f^{(k)}(x) | $  going to 0 as $|x|$ tends to $ \infty $  for each given pair m and k ( non negative  integers)

Comment: You mean $f^{(k)}(x)$ rather than $f^l(x)$?

Comment: yes it is derivative

Comment: Why both $k$ and $l$ still?

Comment: I hope my assumption that $k=l$ was correct.  In the future it would be easier if you edit when asked to clarify your notation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  To see that the original property implies the second, note that if you didn't have $x^m f^{(k)}(x)$ going to $0$ at infinity, then $x^{m+1}f^{(k)}(x)$ would be unbounded.  To see that the second property implies the original, note that by continuity $x^{m}f^{(k)}(x)$ is bounded on bounded intervals, and if it goes to $0$ at $\infty$, then you can make it arbitrarily small outside sufficiently large bounded intervals, getting boundedness on the entire real line.